# Save as .CSV and .txt

Tags: vba, excel

I am sure this is straightforward but is baffling me beyond belief. I have written the below code. You can see in to places that I am saving My pay final and Non-mypay Final as CSV files. Is there a way I can get the files to save as txt files as well. Ideally with the same location if possible? As always, your help is greatly appreciated.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub BACSConversion()

 Dim MyNewBook As String
 Dim MySaveFile As String
 Dim fileToOpen As Variant
 Dim fileName As String
 Dim sheetName As String
 Dim rCopy As Range

 'Turn off display alerts
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 'Turn off screen updates
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
  ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

 'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
  fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If
 'Creates the file name based on txt file name
  fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
 'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
  sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

 'Save active file as...
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
  fileName & ".CSV")

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
  Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

 'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
   Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
 (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\bacs conversation calc.xlsx"
 'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
  Sheets("Original").Range("A:A").ClearContents

 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
  rCopy.Copy
  Sheets("Original").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
   Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

  'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
   Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
  Selection.Copy

  'Add a new workbook
   Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
 'Save template file as...
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile)
 'Close the new saved file
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

 'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
   Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
 Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy

 'Add a new workbook
  Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
 'Save template file as...
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile)
  'Close the new saved file
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
 'Close original source workbook (template)
  Workbooks("bacs conversation calc").Close

 'Turn on display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 'Turn on screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Note that your current `SaveAs` is just saving the file as a tab-delimited text file, but with a file extension of `.csv`, which will confuse people who expect that it is a comma-separated values file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you save it as a `.csv` file, just re-do the same code but instead of `.csv` change it to `.txt`

But that won't necessarily change the type of file.  After your `Activeworkbook.SaveAs` command, add `FileFormat:= xlTextWindows`. This will actually save it as a textfile.

It should look like:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:= xlTextWindows`

I would recommend also looking up the multiple different types of "FileFormats" when it comes to saving workbooks, just to familiarize yourself with them.  Just search Excel FileFormats, and you should be able to find information about all of them.

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, your CSV file you are saving may not be actually saving as comma delimited.  To do so, similarly to what I said above, you can change the fileformat of your initial save to `xlCSV`. This can be achieved by adding `FileFormat:= xlcsv` to the end of your first `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`

FileFormats are required when you are actually interested in changing the filetype and not just the extension.  Here is the link to the MSDN site explaining all the different formats. [MSDN XLFileFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel).  Instead of using the text `xlCSV` or `xlTextWindows` you can also use the numeric values assigned to those formats.  Instead of `FileFormat:= xlCSV` you can do `FileFormat:= 6` or for `xlTextWindows` you can do `FileFormat:= 20`

Comment: The existing `SaveAs` is already saving it as tab-delimited (because that was how it was opened), so you might have to expand the answer to tell the OP how to save as a csv file.

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice it was opening that way.  Updated my answer.

Comment: @Busse Thank you so much for you wonderful and detailed answer. Not only has it worked like a charm but you have given me some extra learning which is really useful.

Comment: I have one final question surrounding this routine if you can help? After running this, I am left with the original CSV file open that was created from the original text file, is there a way to overwrite the filename of the original text document to include !DNU! so once the macro is executed, users will know not to select it again? Does that make sense?

Comment: Also is there a simple line of code which will close any other workbooks still open except the workbook where the macro lives?

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please mark it as the correct answer :)

As for your other question(s), once you open the file you can just `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` at the beginning and change the FileName to whatever you want, then when you do your Saves later in the code they will rename the file to what you would like.  Best thing to do would be to store the activeworkbook as a variable (`Dim wb as Workbook, wb = Activeworkbook` and then after you're done saving, do `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`)

Comment: For your second question, you can do something like `For Each Book in Workbooks` and then `If Book.Name <> "Insert Workbook Name or Variable Here" Then` `Book.Close SaveChanges:=False` `End If` `Next`

Each of those should go on separate lines, comments don't allow me to format very well.

Comment: @Busse Your closing of the workbooks comment makes perfect sense and has done the trick. Overwriting the original file name seems more tricky, the SaveAs function allows me to create another copy with what ever I choose but does not overwrite the original file name. Each time this macro is used, the file being selected at the start will have a different name, I need to be able to keep that name, add !DNU! and save and close. Is that even possible?

Comment: You already do that actually. Your variable, sheetname, is the current workbooks name.  Just do: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("FILE LOCATION HERE" & sheetname & "!DNU!.txt/csv/whateverfileextensionyouwant")`

Comment: @Busse Thank you for that, I am not sure if I am putting that line of code in the right place though as it doesn't seem to do anything at all! I have put it after the first active file save as. 'Save active file as...
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
    fileName & ".CSV"), FileFormat:=xlCSV
'Rename the original text file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited" & sheetName & "!DNU!" & ".txt")

Comment: Put it before the first save as. You said you just want to rename the original, Right?

Comment: @Busse I am sorry to say it doesn't do anything even if I move it to where you suggested. I just need to get the filename overwritten successfully and you will have helped me gain some serious brownie points!

Comment: Can you post this as a separate question and I'll post a solution there. We're getting away from the initial question and I'd rather they be separate.